# How does this code snippet in the Pom file works out?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, pom.xml

Help me on this code snippet given below,I was not able to get what it exactly do?

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
<directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>0.6.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration
<generatePackage>com.sample.modelclasses</generatePackage>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

What does the GeneratePackage does here?

Comment: Why go to the effort of making an image of some text, when you could simply have pasted the text itself? This didn't need to be an image: replace it with the actual text

Comment: Text is also better because you can find it via Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually maven-jaxb2-plugin  compiles the  XML Schemas,Schema file will be  under src/main/resources folder and during Runtime  it generate a "com.sample.modelclasses" package(which is specified in POM) under target/generated-source folder based on schema present in xml file

Here is the link which helped me:  [look here](https://java.net/projects/maven-jaxb2-plugin/pages/Home)

Answer (score 0):

> This Maven plugin wraps and enhances the JAXB Schema Compiler (XJC) and allows compiling XML Schemas (as well as WSDL, DTDs, RELAX NG) into Java classes in Maven builds.

source: [project website](https://java.net/projects/maven-jaxb2-plugin/pages/Home)

Does this answer your question or did I get your wrong?